# Can we deploy domain projects into Server groups or server clusters?

Tags: mule4

I have a domain project and I am trying to deploy application in both server group and cluster. Is this possible for domain projects? Please let me know.

I am able to deploy on-premises applications to server group and server cluster.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deploy through Anypoint Runtime Manager then the answer is no, because it doesn't support deploying Mule domain projects.

Comment: okay @aled. Is there any other way to deploy domain projects in server group and cluster?

Comment: Not in server groups because those exists only as Runtime Manager logical groupings. In cluster, only deploying the domain individually to each node in the cluster. That applies to nodes in a group too.

Comment: Got it. Even if one of the nodes is down then the information is shared by other nodes in cluster. Thanks @aled

Comment: That's a different topic but Mule cluster share automatically some information in distributed memory but not application/domain deployments. You can use Runtime Manager for applications but you'll need some other deployment method for domains.

Comment: Can you please refer a link for deploying domain projects in Runtime Manager (cluster) or let me know the process?

Comment: As I mentioned Runtime Manager does not support deploying domains. You can deploy by copying the domain jar file manually into each node domains subdirectory.

Comment: I have done this manually, copying the domain jar in domains directory. It is working fine but if we have 2 nodes and the domain jar is copied and pasted in 2 nodes - domains directory and start mule. whichever node starts first, the mule application is deployed in Runtime Manager and seen in that node apps directory, the other node fails. Is this the expected behaviour with domain projects?

Comment: It depends on the details of the issue. And that's a different topic. You should open a new question for that.

Comment: okay @aled. Thanks!